# How to check the consistency of OLS estimator in macroeconomic models

Tags: least-squares, estimation, economics, linear-regression

**Problem:**
We have a model $$C_t = a + b Y_t + e_t$$ and $$ Y_t = C_t + I_t$$ It's known that $Cov(I, e)$ is zero.
A student estimates the following model: $$C_t = a + b Y_t + e_t$$
**Are the estimators $\hat a_{OLS} = \hat a$ and $\hat b_{OLS} = \hat b$ consistent? If not, then recommend the consistent estimators.**

**My attempt:**
I think that both of the estimators are inconsistent because the model is kind of a recursive one with two equations, while the student regress only one function.

Then I tried to prove it using formulas. I start with the slope estimator and there is a formula for the slope that reminds omitted variable bias:

$$ \hat b = b +  \frac{(1/n)\sum(y - \bar y)(u - \bar u)}{(1/n) \sum(y - \bar y)^2}$$

Then I take $\text{plim}$ of the numerator and denominator.

$$\text{plim}[ (1/n) \sum(y - \bar y)^2] = Var(y) \neq 0$$
$$\text{plim}[ (1/n)\sum(y - \bar y)(u - \bar u)] = Cov(y,u)$$

At this step, I don't know how to evaluate $Cov(y,u)$ is either zero or not zero.

I also assumed that this formula is wrong, and instead tried to use the formula for the OLS estimator of the slope. However, when I tried to substitute $C_t$ I received a recursive equation.

Can you give me help?

Comment: What is ***u***? Is it $Y_t = C_t + I_t$ or $Y_t = C_t + I_t + error$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you considered the model as one equation. However, as you wrote yourself, there are *two* equation, not one. The problem you faced is called the simultaneous equations.
Your equations are given in the *structural form*. Try to rewrite them in *reduced form* and then apply the logic to showed in your attempt.